# Can Extra Trees regressor handling with missing values in Sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tree, regression, missing-data

I am doing a project with sklearn.tree.ExtraTreeRegressor. It does not handle missing values. All tree-based algorithms handle the missing value internally. I have revised the info in the sklearn website and I have not found anything. Also, I have consulted the original paper by Geurts et al 2006 (Extremely randomized trees) and there is no clear information about it.

I understand that ExtraTreeRegressor cannot internally deal with missing values, is this correct?.
Is it something specific to the algorithm? or is it due to its implementation in sklearn?.
Is there a document or paper where this is explicitly stated?

Thanks.

I have been looking for information regarding this issue and I expect a answer with a document or a paper with the answer.